# Print the environment variables using environ

Tags: c, environment-variables

How to print the environment variables in a C program using `environ`.

```c
extern char **environ
```

Comment: I wrote a demo program which you might find useful and informative, here: [environment_variables_environ_and_main_envp.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/environment_variables_environ_and_main_envp.c)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char **environ;
//...

int i = 0;
while(environ[i]) {
  printf("%s\n", environ[i++]); // prints in form of "variable=value"
}
```

Comment: exactly what i needed? So environ is actually an array of character pointers right? and each character pointer in the array points to an environment variable right??

Comment: Each pointer points to a string (yeah, char array) of the form "variable=value". The last entry is a null-pointer, which ends the loop above.

Comment: You forgot `extern char **environ;`. While some nonstandard systems may declare it in a header file, POSIX specifies that it is not available unless you declare it yourself manually.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    while(*envp!=null) {
        printf("%s\n", *envp);
        envp++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, `extern char **environ;` is POSIX standard. This signature for `main` is completely nonstandard.

Comment: You are completely correct.  However.  That was why I asked.  It compiles and runs correctly under gcc on Solaris 9 & 10, under cc on HPUX 10i, 11.0, and 11i. It also compiled and ran on older versions of DEC Unix and DGUX.  The point being that people get **environ and the old int main( int, char **, char *) confused.  I don't have my K&R  around to verify or I would claim it in there as well. What does your K&R say?

Comment: Upvoted because this is perfectly valid GNU C (via gcc compiler), but, as @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE said, it is _not_ POSIX compliant. See the gcc user manual here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Program-Arguments: **The third argument `envp` gives the program’s environment; it is the same as the value of `environ`. See Environment Variables. POSIX.1 does not allow this three-argument form, so to be portable it is best to write main to take two arguments, and use the value of `environ`.**