# Print address of last environ

Tags: c, linux

I need to print the last address of the enviroment.

I know I can get the first address with this (Or I think I did).

```
extern char **environ;
printf("first address %p\n",&(*environ));
```

But what about the last address?

Comment: Could you make it more clear to us?

Comment: See http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

Comment: Did you search the SO site before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291080/print-the-environment-variables-using-environ

Comment: @JensGustedt ACK. While it is not the very same, the difference can (nearly) trivially be accomplished.

Answer (score 6):

`man environ` is a good place to start.

```
char **pp = environ;
for( ; *pp; pp++) {
   printf("%s\n", *pp);
} 
printf("The end of environ is %p\n", pp);
```

Will print out the environment variables; I believe they are in the form of "name=value".

Asking about the last one seems strange as they are in no particular order except maybe the order in which they were set in the shell.

Comment: it was a question from an america sch, wanting the ending address of the enviroment.

Comment: ITYM `char **`, not `char *`.

Comment: @glglgl , thanks! Only you noticed that! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally, as documented by [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), the `environ` array ends with a `NULL` pointer.

<sup>Actually, the kernel sets up the initial stack of a process after an  [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), and the environment is passed on that initial stack with an ending `NULL`. So part of that convention is implemented in the kernel, per the [application binary interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). The other part of the convention is implemented in the startup routine -which is the entry point of the executable- in `crt*.o` which is calling `main` and setting `environ`.</sup>

So you just have to make a loop like in [Charlie Burns' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19408553/841108) to find its end, e.g

```
char** environ_end;
for (environ_end = environ; *environ_end != NULL; environ_end ++) {};
// at this point, environ_end points to the end of the environment
// i.e. to the ending NULL entry there.
```

Comment: but I only want to print the ending address of the enviroment.

Comment: You still have to make the loop (without printing).

Comment: How do I check if it reaches the end then?

Answer (score 2):

If the array of environ is NULL terminated, (as in the sometimes 3rd parameter of `main()`)

```
extern char **environ;

int i = 0;
while (environ[i] != NULL) {
  printf("environ[%d] = %p\n", i, environ[i]);
  i++;
}
// environ is a "pointer to pointer to char".  See http://cdecl.org/
// The last useful pointer in array `environ` should be a NULL.
printf("last address(or pointer) of the environment = %p\n", environ[i]);
// The address(pointer) of that last pointer(pointer) is ...
printf("address of the last address of environ = %p\n", &environ[i]);
```